# Apache Airflow 1.9 : Dataflow exception at the job's end

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

I am using Airflow 1.9 to launch a Dataflow on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) thanks to a DataflowJavaOperator.

Below, the code used to launch dataflow from an Airflow Dag :

```
df_dispatch_data = DataFlowJavaOperator(
    task_id='df-dispatch-data',  # Equivalent to JobName
    jar="/path/of/my/dataflow/jar",
    gcp_conn_id="my_connection_id",
    dataflow_default_options={
        'project': my_project_id,
        'zone': 'europe-west1-b',
        'region': 'europe-west1',
        'stagingLocation': 'gs://my-bucket/staging',
        'tempLocation': 'gs://my-bucket/temp'
    },
    options={
        'workerMachineType': 'n1-standard-1',
        'diskSizeGb': '50',
        'numWorkers': '1',
        'maxNumWorkers': '50',
        'schemaBucket': 'schemas_needed_to_dispatch',
        'autoscalingAlgorithm': 'THROUGHPUT_BASED',
        'readQuery': 'my_query'
    }
)
```

However, even if all is right on GCP because the job succeed, an exception occured at the end of the dataflow job on my compute Airflow. It is thrown by the gcp_dataflow_hook.py :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 528, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1584, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 121, in execute
    hook.start_java_dataflow(self.task_id, dataflow_options, self.jar)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 152, in start_java_dataflow
    task_id, variables, dataflow, name, ["java", "-jar"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 146, in _start_dataflow
    self.get_conn(), variables['project'], name).wait_for_done()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._job = self._get_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 48, in _get_job
    job = self._get_job_id_from_name()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 40, in _get_job_id_from_name
    for job in jobs['jobs']:
KeyError: 'jobs'
```

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by options used to launch the dataflow. If --zone or --region are given the google API to get job status does not work, only if default zone and regions, US/us-central1.

Comment: So does this mean we cannot run DataFlow jobs anywhere but US/us-central1 ?

Comment: I managed to solve this but reducing the 'poll_sleep' param of DataFlowPythonOperator from 10 to 1, as my teste DataFlow job was completing before the interval.